# Browserify Module not found

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am trying to use the 'typestring' npm module with browserify but get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'typescript-api'
```

I see that 'typescript-api' is a dependency of typestring and it does appear in the node_modules folder of 'typestring'...

Am i missing something? My grunt-browserify task is:

```
browserify: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                './public/bundle.js': './public/main.js'
            },
            options: {
                commondir: true,
                bundleOptions: {
                    debug: true
                },
                transform: ['deamdify']
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, have you tried running "npm install" inside the  the "typestring" folder? Seems odd but that worked for me in another project...

Comment: Unfortunately that did not seem to work. I am starting to think the issue is with the typescript-api module since it uses the 'fs' module.